# php/mysql. selecting 2 common fields in 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a project about an attendance system using PHP and MySQL. I am having trouble in my SQL syntax. I want to display all the names of the students in my "students" table and the records from the "attendance" table, but I keep on looping 5 extra records in my screen. This is what I've done so far.

```
SELECT students.name as StudentName, attendance.timelogin as TimeLogin, attendance.datelogin as DateLogin FROM students, attendance WHERE students.strand LIKE '%TVL%' AND students.gender ='Male' AND attendance.datelogin LIKE '%{$month}%' AND attendance.timelogin >= '12' ORDER BY students.name ASC;
```

[image: screen-output]

Comment: of the student *from my "students" table

Comment: I don't see that you are joining the 2 tables.

Comment: i want to display P for present, L for late and A for absent in the date number column from the html table.

Comment: i used this earlier but it doesn't display what i desire.

Comment: SELECT students.name as StudentName, attendance.status as Status FROM students LEFT JOIN attendance ON students.student_id = attendance.student_id WHERE attendance.datelogin LIKE '%{$month}%' AND attendance.timelogin >= '12' AND students.strand LIKE '%TVL%'ORDER BY students.name ASC;

Comment: why use left join? use inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the join condition properly, so if you have a primary key `Id` in the students table and another foreign key `studentid` in the attendance table use it. And use ANSI join syntax like this:

```
SELECT 
  s.name as StudentName, 
  a.timelogin as TimeLogin, 
  a.datelogin as DateLogin 
  UPPER(LEFT(status, 1)) AS Status
FROM students AS s 
INNER JOIN attendance AS a ON s.Id = a.StudentId
WHERE s.strand LIKE '%TVL%' 
  AND s.gender ='Male' 
  AND a.datelogin LIKE '%{$month}%' 
  AND a.timelogin >= '12' 
ORDER BY s.name ASC;
```

Comment: how to use variables a and s from this code "FROM students AS s 
INNER JOIN attendance AS a"??

Comment: a and s are just aliases for the names of the tables

Comment: @JanMichaelBesinga Like Lio said, it just aliases you can get rid of them and use the tables full names.

Comment: is it possible to display the 'status' record for each day in a row using a while loop?

Comment: i want to display P for present, L for late and A for absent in the date number column from the html table.

Comment: @JanMichaelBesinga - Yes sure, from where is this status? from which table??

Comment: @StephenParker its from the 'attendance' table sir.

Comment: i have my screen output at my post if u can see it. My attendance table consist 5 columns, ID | student_id | timelogin | datelogin | status